# Scipy fmin_bfgs Error: Divide-by-zero encountered: rhok assumed large

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy

I'm getting the following error when using **fmin_bfgs** (in SciPy) to optimize an unregularized logistic cost function:

> Divide-by-zero encountered: rhok assumed large
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py:828:
>   RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars   rhok =
>   1.0 / (numpy.dot(yk, sk))
>
> Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
>            Current function value: 0.693147
>            Iterations: 1
>            Function evaluations: 27

The algorithm (fmin_bfgs) stops after one iteration. What could I be doing wrong? Here's the python code: https://gist.github.com/4223554

Here's the dataset: https://gist.github.com/4223566

Answer (score -1, accepted):

folks,

Unlike what 'pv' mentioned, the issue wasn't related to initial_theta. It had to do with the training data set. I've fixed the problem and here's the working code: https://github.com/dormantroot/machine-learning-experiment/blob/master/LogisticRegressionExamples/LogisticRegression.py

Comment: Your function `f` is defined as `def f(theta): return np.ndarray.flatten(self.compute_cost(self.X, self.y, initial_theta))` whose value is obviously independent of `theta`.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective and gradient functions have bugs:

- `initial_theta` instead of `theta`, so they return constant values. Such a function has *no* well-defined minima, hence the optimization fails.
- the gradient function assumes `theta` is 2D array

Fix them and it works.

Comment: pv, can you please elaborate on your first point - "initial_theta instead of theta, so they return constant values. Such a function has no well-defined minima, hence the optimization fails."